# Как сделать ветку replykeyboard кнопок python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

```
 def send_welcome(message):
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Привет', reply_keyboard=keyboard())
 def keyboard():
   markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
   btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Помощь')
   btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Информация')
   btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Орёл и решка')
   btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Кейсы')
   markup.add(btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4)
   return markup
```

Как сделать что бы когда пользователь вводит 'Кейсы' то появлялась другая replykeyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проверяйте через @bot.message_handler текст, отправленный пользователем. если он будет совпадать с текстом из нужной кнопки, то отправляйте сообщение от бота с другим reply_keyboard.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def message(message):
    if message.text == 'Кейсы':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Меню кейсов', reply_keyboard=other_keyboard())
```